# Does AWS Device Farm support CodeCeptJS?

Tags: device, aws-device-farm

Can we run the CodeCeptJS works on AWS device farm? Did not see the CodeCeptJS dropdown test methods like Appium TestNG etc.

Answer (score 1):

With Device Farm's [custom environment](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/devicefarm/latest/developerguide/custom-test-environments.html), almost any test library/framework can be used. These test types do not require the test package to be parsed currently:

- Appium Node
- Appium Ruby

If you upload the test package as one of those you can then author the testspec.yml file to execute the tests the same way they're executed locally.